# Suggestions on how to make a local navigation map with GPS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

in advance of the asking the question, the question I have is a general programming question in preparation for a project. Please tell me if the format is wrong, or if the tags are put wrong.

I am trying to make an app that shows the user's location on my school's campus, and shows directions to various buildings in my school. I want to use a custom image of our school's map, and be able to tag names to various facilities and buildings.
I thought I could use CLLocationManager and CLLocation for getting the position of the user on my campus, but I'm lost on how I should sync the custom campus map with the MKMap framework that apple provides.

Are there any suggestions on how I should plan on making this app?
Thank you so much.

Comment: If you establish the geocoordinates of the school map image, this should be straightforward. What problem do you see?

Comment: Hmm..when you say establishing the geocoordinates of the school map image, do you mean I should assign coordinate values to specific parts of the school map image?

Comment: If you just define the coordinate for the upper left and lower right corners, that is enough to calculate the coordinate for any pixel in the map image

Comment: Ah..thank you. But I would have to do additional coding to make zooming in and out possible without any problems, right?

Comment: Yes, you just rescale the corners